# how to disable recycler view scrolling so that it listens to Scrollview layout?

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view inside a ScrollView. I want to disable the recycler view scroll so that it listens to its parent layout, A ScrollView!

Comment: read ViewGroup docs, pay attention on intercepting MotionEvents

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RecyclerView inside ScrollView is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27083091/recyclerview-inside-scrollview-is-not-working)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Logically, it is not a good idea to put `ListView` inside a `ScrollView`. However, if you insist then:

- You may either increase the `ListView` height based on the sum of its
  rows height as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3495908/966550).
- Or let the recycling in place but intercept the touch on `ListView`
  to redirect scrolling to its parent ScrollView as mentioned
  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23293159/966550).

Comment: Great. Finally I sorted it out. What I did is dynamically using my recycler view layout position. Problem solved !

Comment: @Abhilash, Please share the answer.

Comment: @MuhammadRiyaz i have used this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27616854/3736955 . But scrolling scrollview is not smooth . So used below answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/32283439/3736955) to make it smooth

Answer (score 46):

This should solve your RecyclerView nested scrolling.

```
 mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

[RecyvlerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) implements [NestedScrollingChild](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/NestedScrollingChild.html)

for instance if RecyclerView parent is a ScrollView or ListView or RecyclerView or any AbsListView

disable scrolling for the child RecyclerView.

Comment: this is exacly what i need. I love u

Comment: Spent some time trying to fix this by my own by adjusting motion events until I saw your answer which fixed it right away. @Tim, I don't see why this wouldn't work pre Lollipop?

Comment: @Tim I can confirm this works on Google Nexus 4 - 4.1.1 API 16

Comment: @Tim not true, NestedScrollingChild and RecyclerView are part of the support libraries

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in xml,

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
```